# Values for Principal and SecretAlias ID in PGP encryption

Tags: pgp

While configuring PGP encryption what values we have to pass for **principal** and **Secret Alias ID**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PGP encryption principal is nothing but the username in the key that is it is a combination of name and email ID you specified while generating the keys
ex: smith .
 and coming to Secret alias ID GPA tool does not provide this value.we have to provide some random value, deploy application and run your flow.Mule will throw an exception in the console you can also the list of keys that is Secret Alias ID that what we want.[In console we can find suggested Secret Alias ID like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eoslx.png)

Comment: Thank you so much @chdivya. Its working  Got the output